# rand() generates same numbers when used with fork()

Tags: c

I'm trying to generate random numbers in a specific range. I'm also using children processes in my program.

However, the `rand()` function generates the same number, say 550, in the for loop even though I have randomized it using `srand()`

Here is the code for demonstration:

```
int main()
{

int count = 5;
int i;
  for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
  {
    pid_t pid = fork();
    if (pid == 0)
    {

      // random number between 500 and 700
      srand(time(NULL));
      int random = rand() % 100 + 500;
      printf("%d\n", random);

      exit(0);
    }
    else
    {

      wait(NULL);
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Where is the problem? How can I fix that?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Well, `time(NULL)` is probably giving the same seed value to all of these processes, as it is happening very fast. Add some process specific value to it (such as `time(NULL)+i` for example)

Comment: @EugeneSh. I tried it but again the same story...

Comment: It works for me.

Comment: I get `524
531
538
545
552
` first time, then `571
578
585
592
599
` next time

Comment: Just tried myself. Getting same numbers with your code and different numbers with `srand(i+time(NULL));`

Comment: @EugeneSh.Thank you so much! Now it works when I substitute it with the value of i. I wish you wrote it as an answer so that I could accept it as the answer.

Comment: Added as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All of the processes your program is spawning are created very fast, so the value returned by the call `time(NULL)` is the same for all of them. It is passed as a seed to the pseudo random number generator, making it to produce the same sequence of pseudo-random numbers for each process.

In order to get different numbers in each process, you should make sure each process gets a unique seed value. Simplest way to achieve this would be to add the counter `i` to the time value:

```
srand(i + time(NULL));
```